# Can I determine a parameter in the objective function of a convex problem, given the optimal solution?

Tags: convex-optimization, parameter-estimation

Considering a convex optimization problem with inequality constraints:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{x\in\Re^{n}} & ~x^\top H x + f^\top x + \lambda\sqrt{x^\top R x}\\
\text{s.t.} & ~Ax\leq b  
\end{aligned},
\end{equation}
where both matrices $H$ and $R$ are positive definite. If the optimal solution $x^*$ is given and assume that the non-negative scalar $\lambda$ is unknown, I am wondering, is it possible to estimate the value of the $\lambda$?

Many Thanks!

Comment: The inequality $\ Ax<b\ $ typically means that *every* entry of the column vector on the left side of the inequality is strictly less than the corresponding entry of $\ b\ $.  Is that the case here?  If it is, then the problem with the constraint will have an optimal solution if and only there's an optimal solution of the *unconstrained* problem which satisfies the constraint.

Comment: Shouldn't $\lambda >0$ be a constraint. Because it seems that otherwise the problem could become unbounded

Comment: @rostader I guess $\ \lambda\ $ could be zero, but if it were *strictly negative*, then I don't believe the objective function would be convex on $\ \mathbb{R}^n\ $, although I haven't formally checked that.  So yes, $\ \lambda\ $ must be restricted to non-negative values. However, I gather  it's supposed to be a fixed constant whose value is unknown, rather than a variable to be optimised over, so, strictly speaking, $\ \lambda\ge0\ $ isn't a "constraint" of the optimisation problem as such.

Comment: Okay. So I definitely don't understand the problem. Given $x^*$ this reduces to a problem of a function in $\lambda$. So I can choose $\lambda$ to be whatever I want. The constraint doesn't play any role because I already have an $x^*$.  So unless I am given some more information on what the optimal value of the objective function is I can't really say anything about $\lambda$.

Comment: $Ax<b$ or $Ax\le b$?

Comment: @RiverLi less equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some thoughts**:

Let $\theta$ denote the Lagrange multiplier.
Then, $(\lambda, x^\ast, \theta)$ satisfies the system
\begin{align*}
 2Hx^\ast + f + \lambda\frac{Rx^\ast}{\sqrt{(x^\ast)^\mathsf{T} R x^\ast}} + A^\mathsf{T}\theta &= 0, \\
 \theta^\mathsf{T}(Ax^\ast - b) &= 0, \\
 \theta &\ge 0, \\
 \lambda &\ge 0.
\end{align*}
Since the system above is linear in $(\lambda, \theta)$, we can find a feasible $(\lambda, \theta)$ by using convex programming.

I tested some examples (I use cvx + matlab), and it works.

Comment: Thank you, I think your "KKT condition" idea is equivalent to solving littleO's problem (1), but I will try it!

Comment: I think because $A\in\Re^{(2n+2)\times n}$,      the feasible solution $(\lambda,\theta)$ will not be unique.

Comment: @StephenGe So, it fails for your examples? I used cvx to minimize $\lambda$ subject to the linear system which return the desired.

Comment: I tried, it works & it is fast, thanks

Comment: @StephenGe Nice. We need to prove that $\lambda$ is unique.

Comment: Yes, but due to the dimension of matrix $A$, I am not sure.....

Comment: @StephenGe Assume there are $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2$ such that $(\lambda_1, \theta_1)$ and $(\lambda_2, \theta_2)$ are two feasible points to the system.  Then the convex optimization problem, for $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, has the same optimal $x^\ast$. Can we prove this is impossible? In other words, can we prove that for different $\lambda > 0$, the convex problem has different optimal $x^\ast$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\gamma = \sqrt{(x^*)^T Rx^*}$. Notice that $x^*$ is a minimizer for the problem
\begin{align}
\tag{1} \text{minimize} & \quad x^T H x + f^T x \\
\text{subject to} &\quad Ax \leq b, \\
&\quad \sqrt{x^T R x} \leq \gamma.
\end{align}

Solve problem (1) using an algorithm such as an interior point method that will compute a Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ for the constraint $\sqrt{x^T R x} \leq \gamma$. According to a Lagrange multiplier theorem, which tells us roughly speaking that hard constraints can be replaced with penalty terms in the objective, $x^*$ is optimal for your original optimization problem with the value of $\lambda$ found by solving problem (1).

The CVX or CVXPY software packages make it easy to solve small instances of problem (1), obtaining Lagrange multipliers for the constraints. That might be an easy way to test out this approach.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your replying. I varied $\lambda$ between 0 and 1, get different optimal solutions $x^*$ and tried to solve problem (1) using MOSEK and get dual variable of the inequality constraint as the estimated $\hat{\lambda}$, however it couldn't give me the correct answer. BTW, what is the problem (2)?

Comment: BTW, solving the problem (1) will get the identical result of the optimal $x^*$

Comment: Oh, writing (2) was a typo, I meant to write problem (1). I fixed that.

Comment: Yes, the $x^*$ you obtain by solving your original problem is optimal for problem (1). So solving (1) will indeed yield the same solution $x^*$.

Comment: What do you mean by "it couldn't give me the correct answer"? Also what's the reason for varying $\lambda$?

Comment: Basically, I tested it using diffent $\lambda$s, $\lambda=1,~0.5,~0.1,~0.001,~0.0001$, solving my original problem via MOSEK, get different group of $x^*$, calculate $\gamma~$s, and then solving your problem (1) using MOSEK again, by checking the corresponding dual variable I got estimated $\hat{\lambda} = 1,~ 1,~1,~1.23,~3.4795 $.

Comment: Hmm. One thing I'd like to check is if the solution to problem (1) is always optimal for your original problem with the value of $\lambda$ obtained by solving problem (1). Do you observe that to be the case?

Comment: two problems get almost identical optimals, I also check the first derivative of the Lagrange function of your problem (1), most of them are around 1e-12, very few point are within +/- 1e-6

Comment: BTW, the scale of $x$ in my problem is about 4800. When solving ends, MOSEK returns:   "Problem status  : PRIMAL_AND_DUAL_FEASIBLE;   Solution status : OPTIMAL"  for both problem.

Comment: So just to be totally clear, if you do the following steps: 1) Solve problem (1) with a particular value of $\gamma$, obtaining $x^\star$ and $\lambda^\star$ ; 2) then solve your original problem with $\lambda = \lambda^\star$; then you observe that the solution to the original problem (with $\lambda = \lambda^\star$) is the same as $x^\star$?

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding, if I substitude the estimated $\hat{\lambda}$ back to my original problem, then I will get completely different optimal.

Comment: @StephenGe Do you observe that the completely different optimal solution you obtain is actually better [lower objective function value] than $x^\star$? Or is it merely tied with $x^\star$?

Comment: The difference is significant. For example, I use $\lambda = 0.0001$, the optimal value of my original problem is -5.37e5. If I substitude the optimal $x$ that is calculated using estimated $\hat{\lambda} = 3.4795$ into my original problem, I got objective function = -3.6488e5, which is much worse.